# show and hide div when clicking anywhere

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I want to hide a div when the page loads and then when a user clicks anywhere on the page, it displays and remains visible.

This is the code I have, but the div doesn't appear hidden when the page loads:

```
$(function(){
    // body click
    $("body").click(function(){

        // element to toggle
        var $el = $(".search");

        // toggle div
        if ($el.is(":none")) {
            // fade out
            $el.fadeIn(400);
        } else {
            // fade in
            $el.fadeOut(400);                
        }

    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If it's supposed to remain visible, why are you hiding it when clicking again (ignoring the fact that there is no :none selector)

Comment: ":none" is it custom selector expression or what???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS to hide it:;

```
.search {display:none}
```

Comment: To the person who wants to edit the semicolon, it's not needed if its the last property/before the closing bracket

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var $el = $(".search");
$($el).hide();
$(document).click(function () {
    $($el).fadeToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.search{display:none;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDabF/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait for the scripts to load on your page to hide the div, add display:none; to the search class

```
.search {
    display:none;
    /*other stuff*/
}
```

Then your element will start out hidden until you click the body.

Answer (score 0):

write this script in your page script page...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".search").css('display','')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Including `$(this).off();` will remove the click event so it is no longer called when the page is clicked.

HTML

```
<div class="search hidden"></div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
(function () {
    $(document).click(function () {
        $(".search").removeClass('hidden').hide().fadeIn(400);
        $(this).off();
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this method and it works. However, I have a form within my div and the select dropdowns no longer drop down. Could this be caused by the above?

Comment: It shouldn't, I have tried to replicate this - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7eZhG/) - but the form seems to work. Can you provide more information or update the fiddle to show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the $(document) selector is referring to the actual page, so we can do this:

```
$(document).click(function(){



    });
```

this is more stable than doing $("body").click()

the code inside $(document).click will get activated each time the document is clicked.

so inside we can put fadeToggle(). fadeToggle() will fade something in or out depending on if it is hidden or visible. Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

so now we have this:

```
$(document).click(function(){

    $(".search").fadeToggle();

});
```

however, the div is visible on page load.

to hide the div automatically when the page loads, we use this CSS:

```
.search{
 display: none;   
}
```

which will hide all divs with a class of search on DOM load.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W8Drs/)

Hope it helped!!

**Note**: if you want the div to remain visible after the document being clicked once, you can change the fadeToggle() to fadeIn():

```
$(document).click(function(){

        $(".search").fadeIn();

    });
```